# Nested if statements in cobol

Tags: if-statement, nested, cobol, gnucobol

I am trying to use nested if statements in Cobol. As far as I can tell I am following the style guides, but keep receiving the error:

`file_name.cob:64: Error: syntax error, unexpected ELSE`

^^ (This is the second ELSE statement)

The purpose of the code is to function as a Caesar cipher, but it seems to only be the nested `if` statements that are producing the error. I tried putting the nested statements after the `ELSE` clause of the initial `IF` statement, but that was unsuccessful as well.

*edit*: I am using open-cobol, and and compiling with the `-free` option

```
    IF CharCount < 26 
                    ADD firstnum, CharCount GIVING stringShift.
                    DISPLAY stringShift.
                
                    IF FUNCTION MOD(stringShift, 26) IS NOT ZERO 
                                                        
                            MOVE FUNCTION MOD(stringShift, 26) to stringShift
                            DISPLAY stringShift
            
                            MOVE abc(stringShift:stringShift) TO newChar
                            DISPLAY newChar
            
                            STRING newString DELIMITED BY "", newChar DELIMITED BY SIZE INTO newString

                            DISPLAY newString
                    ELSE
                            STRING newString DELIMITED BY "", searchChar DELIMITED BY SIZE INTO newString
                            DISPLAY newString
                    END-IF
            ELSE
                    STRING newString DELIMITED BY "", searchChar DELIMITED BY SIZE INTO newString
                    DISPLAY newString
            END-IF.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to share the answer here, as it was answered in the comp.lang.cobol google group. It was the two periods after the first ADD and DISPLAY lines that were causing the problems. It now compiles successfully.

Comment: I would advicate putting one '.' on a line by itself at the end of each procedure (required). Then search your program for stray '.'. Some will the let you fin the stray '.' in the procedure division. In mainframe ISPF editor the command string X all; F '.' all; X ' . ' all will show the dots in the wrong position in the procedure division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to share the answer here, as it was answered in the comp.lang.cobol google group. It was the two periods after the first ADD and DISPLAY lines that were causing the problems. It now compiles successfully.

The lines should appear as:

```
ADD firstnum, CharCount GIVING stringShift
DISPLAY stringShift
```